# Como evitar a queda do stream quando houver algum quadro inexistente?

Tags: cmd

Estou executando uma linha de comando no ffmpeg para que ele salve o *input* no formato que necessito, porem, o *input stream* tem ocasionalmente algumas falhas, como falta de 5 segundos, e ocorre que o *output* sai com problemas, caso eu esteja usando o VLC para ver o resultado, e ocorrer alguma falha ele para, ou pode deixar de fluir(o stream fica parado).

Como eu poderia contornar isso, para que quando acontecesse, algum frame sem imagens fosse exibido, não interrompendo o fluxo do stream?

Comando ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "input_source" -loglevel verbose -vcodec copy -acodec copy  -hls_time 5 -hls_wrap 3 -f hls  -y "C:\teste\camera.m3u8"
```